# Do Docker buildkit builds appear in `docker images` and `docker ps`? Why not?

Tags: docker

Recent versions of Docker include an overhauled build system called BuildKit that can be used with `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1`. I've noticed when it is running there is no trace of the builds in `docker images` or `docker ps`. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BuildKit runs under runc and containerd rather than directly in docker. This gives it more portability to run in other environments that do not want the full docker daemon installed and running. Because of this architecture, you will only see the resulting image that is exported from BuildKit, and not each of the individual steps as untagged images.

If you're looking to clean up the BuildKit cache, there is `docker builder prune`.

For more details on BuildKit, including how to run it as a standalone container or process, see their github repo: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/